# What's the official name for Vinyl singles printed on papery-like material?

Tags: vinyl

Years ago, I remember seeing (and playing) several Vinyl singles; rather than the more common plastic material, these were printed on a papery-like material that could easily be bent, yet played on a standard record player. Would anybody happen to know what the material used for these types of Vinyls are called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean [flexi discs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexi_disc). These were made of a thin, flexible vinyl sheet, and were sometimes used as a means to include sound with printed material such as magazines and music instruction books before the advent of compact discs.